# Move listitems in SharePoint Hosted app

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-addin, splistitem

I am trying to creating a SharePoint 2013 Hosted app that get a selected listitem and move it to another folder of library in the same web.
When I debug my code everything runs without any problem. The only problem that I have is that the ‘File.moveTo(destinationUrl, true);’ command not works in the ‘context.executeQueryAsync’ function.

I hope that someone can help me further with this.
This is my move function:

```
function moveListItems() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getUrl);

    function getUrl() {
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
                function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execOperation); }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}

    function execOperation() 
    {
        // Load current Web
        context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
        web = appContextSite.get_web();
        context.load(web);

        // Load source list
        list = web.get_lists().getById(selectedListID);
        context.load(list);

        //load source listitem
        sourceItem = list.getItemById(selectedItemID);
        context.load(sourceItem);
        var File = sourceItem.get_file();
        context.load(File);

        context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            if (File != null) {
                var bibName = document.getElementById('listurl').value;
                var fileName = File.get_name();
                var destinationUrl = hostweburl + bibName + fileName;
                File.moveTo(destinationUrl, true);
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: You should use sourcelistitem.file.moveto()